# Calling a method in the background to retrieve data every couple of minutes

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android app to retrieve data through php,mysql,json from a database. I need to create a service or any way to call ***getData()*** method every 10 minutes. I tried placing these 2 methods in a broadcast receiver and used alarm manager to repeat every 10 mins but it didn't run properly, it worked only for ***Toast*** and ***Log.d*** (simple operations). Is there an simple approach to achieve what I want ? I did search a lot, but couldn't find a clear answer

```
 //METHOD 1
 private void getData() {

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}




 // METHOD 2
private void showJSON(String response){

    String id="";
    String time="";
    String value = "";
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tempData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            id = tempData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            time = tempData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            value = tempData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
            String data = "Id:\t"+id+", Time:\t" +time+ ", Value:\t"+ value;
            all += data+"\n";
        }



    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText(all);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way of using a broadcast receiver (BR) and an Alarm manager sounds like a good approach and I'm not sure exactly what problem you encountered. Could you tell us more?

Without all the details I'd say that a potential problem is that a Broadcast receiver is normally executed in the UI thread of Android and that does not for example allow you to perform network access and it must finish within X seconds.

1) You don't have the right permissions to access internet? From what I remember the log of this can be easy to miss.
2) Either you can request the BR to run the a background thread, I know you can do it, not tried myself.
3) You can start another thread. As you seen to update the UI you should probably use an Async Task for this. So you can do the network in a background thread and then you you get a call in the UI thread with the new data. (This would probably be the option to go to)

Side note: for parsing json, I'd recommend you to look at Gson. It's a library from google that makes the parsin of Json much simpler. https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.TaskParams;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.OneoffTask;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.PeriodicTask;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.rcsplcms.ess.Constant;
import com.rcsplcms.ess.GPSTracker;
import com.rcsplcms.ess.R;
import com.rcsplcms.ess.application.ESSApplication;
import com.rcsplcms.ess.util.AppLog;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
* Created by MAYURKUMAR TERAIYA on 20-09-2017.
*/

public class GCMServiceTracking extends GcmTaskService {


private static final String TAG = GCMServiceTracking.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String GCM_ONEOFF_TAG = "oneoff|[0,0]";
public static final String GCM_REPEAT_TAG = "repeat|[7200,1800]";

@Override
public void onInitializeTasks() {
    //called when app is updated to a new version, reinstalled etc.
    //you have to schedule your repeating tasks again
    super.onInitializeTasks();
}

@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    //do some stuff (mostly network) - executed in background thread (async)

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Executed", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //obtain your data
    Bundle extras = taskParams.getExtras();

    Handler h = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    Log.v(TAG, "onRunTask");


    if (taskParams.getTag().equals(GCM_ONEOFF_TAG)) {
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Toast.makeText(GCMServiceTracking.this, "ONEOFF executed", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else if (taskParams.getTag().equals(GCM_REPEAT_TAG)) {
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Toast.makeText(GCMServiceTracking.this, "REPEATING executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(GCMServiceTracking.this);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Syncing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
    return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}



public static void scheduleOneOff(Context context) {
    //in this method, single OneOff task is scheduled (the target service 
   that will be called is MyTaskService.class)
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("some key", "some budle data");
    try {
        OneoffTask oneoff = new OneoffTask.Builder()
                //specify target service - must extend GcmTaskService
                .setService(GCMServiceTracking.class)
                //tag that is unique to this task (can be used to cancel task)
                .setTag(GCM_ONEOFF_TAG)
                //executed between 0 - 10s from now
                .setExecutionWindow(10, 10)
                //set required network state, this line is optional
                .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_ANY)
                //request that charging must be connected, this line is optional
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                //set some data we want to pass to our task
                .setExtras(data)
                //if another task with same tag is already scheduled, replace it with this task
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build();
        GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context).schedule(oneoff);
        Log.v(TAG, "oneoff task scheduled");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void scheduleRepeat(Context context) {
    //in this method, single Repeating task is scheduled (the target service that will be called is MyTaskService.class)
    try {
        PeriodicTask periodic = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
                //specify target service - must extend GcmTaskService
                .setService(GCMServiceTracking.class)
                //repeat every 60 seconds
                .setPeriod(300)
                //specify how much earlier the task can be executed (in seconds)
                .setFlex(30)
                //tag that is unique to this task (can be used to cancel task)
                .setTag(GCM_REPEAT_TAG)
                //whether the task persists after device reboot
                .setPersisted(true)
                //if another task with same tag is already scheduled, replace it with this task
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                //set required network state, this line is optional
                .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_ANY)
                //request that charging must be connected, this line is optional
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .build();
        GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context).schedule(periodic);
        Log.v(TAG, "repeating task scheduled");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "scheduling failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void cancelOneOff(Context context) {
    GcmNetworkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .cancelTask(GCM_ONEOFF_TAG, GCMServiceTracking.class);
}

public static void cancelRepeat(Context context) {
    GcmNetworkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .cancelTask(GCM_REPEAT_TAG, GCMServiceTracking.class);
}

public static void cancelAll(Context context) {
    GcmNetworkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .cancelAllTasks(GCMServiceTracking.class);
}
```

}

```
// CODE FOR START BACKGROUND TASK

GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
Int errorCheck = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(LoginActivity.this);

           if(errorCheck == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                    //google play services available, hooray
                } else if(api.isUserResolvableError(errorCheck)) {
                    //GPS_REQUEST_CODE = 1000, and is used in onActivityResult
                    api.showErrorDialogFragment(LoginActivity.this, errorCheck, GPS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    //stop our activity initialization code
                    return;
                } else {
                    //GPS not available, user cannot resolve this error
                    //todo: somehow inform user or fallback to different 
                  method
                    //stop our activity initialization code
                    return;
 }

GCMServiceTracking.scheduleRepeat(LoginActivity.this);


GRADLE FILE
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

MENIFEST FILE
    <service
        android:name=".services.GCMServiceTracking"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```